# camera_windows save picture to different directory

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I am using the flutter package camera_windows using the exact sample code listed here
[camera_windows](https://pub.dev/packages/camera_windows/example)

It looks like by default it saves it to the "Pictures" directory in windows but I was wondering how do I save it to a different directory with a different filename also it looks like I cant pass a "path" to the call of the function for example

```
final XFile file = await CameraPlatform.instance.takePicture(_cameraId);
_showInSnackBar('Picture captured to: ${file.path}');
```

Comment: An alternative can be you move the file to your directory with the desired name.

Comment: @Manish Dayma - yes that works but I ran into another problem I am just trying to add a simple TextField and it gives the error Could not load source 'dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart': <source not available>.

Comment: I don't think its related to this.